# How ec2 autoscaling work when rebooting the ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have to make a web app (with a redis database) highly available on aws, I'm still debuting and I was asking myself a question

It seems that with AWS Ec2 auto scaling, the EC2 will restart in case of failure, but what of the volume ? After each restart are all data lost ? The volume is kept and only the ami ec2 is relaunched ? (same for ECS and amazon auto scaling)

Thank you for reading me !

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of EC2 you have.

With Instance Store, the data is lost when your EC2 instance is terminated. When using EBS, the data layer is preserved.

There is more information in the [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/instance-store-vs-ebs/).

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that with AWS Ec2 auto scaling, the EC2 will restart in case of failure

This is not correct. The EC2 instance will be Terminated (deleted) and an entirely new instance will be created. The disk volume in this scenario will not be preserved.

Comment: With EBS it seems it will not be the case, isn't it ?

Comment: You could set a flag to keep the EBS volume from being deleted. However the EBS volume will not be reattached to the new instance, it will just be saved in your AWS account. If you want to use auto-scaling you really can't store anything on the EC2 volumes that you want to keep around long-term. And if you scale up to more than 1 server you will have different disk volumes with different data available anyway. There are other options like S3 buckets and EFS volumes for this sort of thing.

Comment: Then everything should be in the AMI ?
How would you handle the need of preserving something on the ec2 ?

Comment: I would handle the need of preserving something in the EC2 by looking into using S3 or EFS, like I already said.